# How can i delete a SubKey in the Registry with a Bachslash(\) in the name?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey, setvalue

I want to delete a SubKey named "**TESTPC02\HANDWERK**".
Every time I save this in a string and try to delete it, the debugger takes two Slashes (\).

I've also tried many different variations of using "@" or more backslashes. Also the Method "Remove" did not work.

Is it even possible that the Debugger only take one?
Or is there another option to delete a SubKey containing a Backslash?

Here is my attempt:

```cs
public static void SetServerValue(string key, string value, string newServerName = "Test")
{
    string writeKey2 = AddBackslash(GetHKLMPath());
    RegistryKey subKey2 = BaseFolderPath.CreateSubKey(writeKey2 + @"Server\\");
    if (newServerName != "")
    {
        subKey2.DeleteSubKey(key);
        subKey2.SetValue(subKey2.CreateSubKey(newServerName).ToString(), value);
    }
    else
    {
        subKey2.SetValue(key, value);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Can you add the code for `AddBackslash`?

Answer (score 0):

Backslash is an escape character, it is used to signify 'the next character is special'.  If you need to include a backslash, then double backslash is the method to use (\\).

(note, the SO editor uses backslash as an escape, so to be able to show 2 backslashes in the previous sentence, I had to enter 4 backslashes!).

`@` is a special instruction to the compiler to say 'don't do any escaping' so `@"\\"` will create a string with 2 backslashes, whereas `"\\"` will create a string with 1 backslash.

```
writeKey2 + @"Server\\"
```

This will result in a string that ends with 2 backslashes.  I doubt that registry keys are allowed to end in a backslash.